# Merge multiple arrays in f#

Tags: f#

I have three sets of information that I need to join together into one array so I can calculate a payment.

**Dataset 1:**
FromDate, ToDate

2013-04-10, 2013-04-16

(i'm currently creating a 2D array of the dates between these two dates using the following)

```
let CalculatedLOS : int =  ToDate.Value.Subtract(FromDate.Value).Days
let internalArray = Array2D.init CalculatedDays, 3, (fun x -> (AdmissionDateValue.AddDays(x),0,0))
```

**Dataset 2:**  These are separated as:   code, date | code, date

87789,2013-04-10|35444,2013-04-14

**Dataset 3:**  These are separated as   date, differentcode  |  date, differentcode

2013-04-10,SE|2013-04-15,EA

What I need to do is somehow match up the dates with the relevant index in the array that is created from the FromDate and ToDate and update the 2nd and 3rd position with the code and differentcode that match to that date.

So I would hopefully end up with a dataset that looked like this

[2013-04-10; 87789; SE]
[2013-04-11;;]
[2013-04-12;;]
[2013-04-13;;]
[2013-04-14;87789;]
[2013-04-15;;EA]
[2013-04-16;;]

I would then iterate over this array to lookup some values and assign a payment based on each day.

I've tried Array.find within a loop to update 2D arrays but I'm not sure how to do it (code below which did **not** work) but I'm really stuck about how to do this, or even if this is the best way.

```
let differentCodeArray  = MyLongString.Value.Split('|')
for i in 0 .. bedStaysArray.Length - 1 do
    Array.find(fun elem -> bedStaysArray.[0].ToString() elem) internalArray
```

Also happy to be directed away from arrays if there's a better way!

Comment: this is a game on creating the correct indexes. If you do create them, you can get rid of intermediate structures : one part create the lookups, another has the 'business logic' that uses it.

Comment: Once you parse the data, you should be able to load the data in a Deedle time series which would deal with the indices: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/timeseries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, given i understand your question. The code have a dependency on the 'correct' DateFormat beeing used.

Full example, dataset1, dataset2, dataset3 are your given inputs.

```
//Given data
let dataset1 = "2013-04-10, 2013-04-16"
let dataset2 = "87789,2013-04-10|35444,2013-04-14"
let dataset3 = "2013-04-10,SE|2013-04-15,EA"

//Extract data
let keyValuePair (c:char) (str:string) = let [|a;b|] = str.Split(c) in a,b
let mapTuple fn a = fn (fst a), fn (snd a)

let date1,date2 = keyValuePair ',' dataset1 |> mapTuple System.DateTime.Parse 

let data2 = 
  dataset2.Split('|') 
  |> Seq.map (keyValuePair ',') 
  |> Seq.map (fun (code, date) -> System.DateTime.Parse date, code)
  |> Map.ofSeq 

let data3 = 
  dataset3.Split('|') 
  |> Seq.map (keyValuePair ',') 
  |> Seq.map (fun (date, code) -> System.DateTime.Parse date, code)
  |> Map.ofSeq 

let rec dateSeq (a:System.DateTime) (b:System.DateTime) = 
  seq {
    yield a.Date
    if a < b then yield!  dateSeq (a.AddDays(1.0)) b
  }

//join data
let getCode data key = match data |> Map.tryFind key with |Some v -> v |None -> ""

let result = 
  dateSeq date1 date2
  |> Seq.map (fun d -> d, getCode data2 d, getCode data3 d)
  |> Seq.toList 


//Format result
result |> List.iter ((fun (date, code1, code2) -> printfn "[%s;%s;%s]" (date.ToShortDateString()) code1 code2))
```

Console output:

```
[2013-04-10;87789;SE]
[2013-04-11;;]
[2013-04-12;;]
[2013-04-13;;]
[2013-04-14;35444;]
[2013-04-15;;EA]
[2013-04-16;;]
```

Comment: Thanks Yodiz that worked really well. I am getting a warning saying "Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[|_; _; _|]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s)." Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: A small amount of concern never killed anyone. :) What it means, for this line: 'let [|a;b|] = str.Split(c) in a,b', is that for instance if the string contains three comma separated values, it will throw an exception.